# Why are there 'nil's in the output of clojure.data/diff?

Tags: clojure

```
user=> (def one [ "a" "b" "c" ])
#'user/one
user=> (def two [ "x" "y" "c" ])
#'user/two
user=> (require 'clojure.data)
nil
user=> (clojure.data/diff one two)
[["a" "b"] ["x" "y"] [nil nil "c"]]
```

Where are those 'nil's coming from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs [`clojure.data/diff`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.data/diff):

> Recursively compares a and b, returning a tuple of
>   [things-only-in-a things-only-in-b things-in-both].
>   Comparison rules:
>
> - For equal a and b, return [nil nil a].
> - Maps are subdiffed where keys match and values differ.
> - Sets are never subdiffed.
> - All sequential things are treated as associative collections
>     by their indexes, with results returned as vectors.
> - Everything else (including strings!) is treated as
>     an atom and compared for equality.

the key point is that your vectors are treated as associative collections, so the `things-in-both` part of result is 'associative', meaning that if the thing in both keyed by 2 in your case (meaning it is at the index of 2 in vector) it should appear by the same key in result. Obviously for vector to include index 2 it should have length of at least 3, that's why it has `nil`s before value, simply being the placeholders for 'nothing'.

one more example:

```
user> (d/diff {:a [1 2 1 4 5] :b 2} {:a [:x 2 :x 4 :x] :b 3})
;;=> ({:b 2, :a [1 nil 1 nil 5]}
;;    {:b 3, :a [:x nil :x nil :x]}
;;    {:a [nil 2 nil 4]}
```